# How to center Google Map on a country by name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I'm using the Google Maps API (v2) and would like to center the map onload to a country (for example england).

At the moment i center the map using:

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 43.907787,-79.359741), 9);
```

But this obviously requires longitude and Latitude.

Any way to do this by inserting a name of a country?

Comment: This question concerns Google Maps API v2, which is expired now. Mabe we should edit it in order to keep it up to date?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var country = "United States"
var map = new GMap2($("#map")[0]);
map.setUIToDefault();

var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLatLng(country, function (point) {
  if (!point) {
    // Handle error
  } else {
    map.setCenter(point, 8, G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
  }
});
```

Comment: The question that i accepted i actually used at first to implement it, but then i moved over to your code which works better in my setup...thanks

Comment: changed this to accepted answer as it's only fair as it's the one finally implemented

Comment: The geocoder also returns ExtendedData which contains a suggested size for the target. [Note that the box isn't a perfect fit for the target location. It's just there to provide sensible zooming.] But that could be exactly what you need in this case, so that you get a different zoom when you centre on England than when you centre on Russia.

See http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_geo3.htm

Comment: In this case how to get **country** lan and lon ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to geocode the address first:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var location = "England";
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
        alert("Could not find location: " + location);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it with the Google Maps API v3. (v2 will stop working at May 2013).

Comment: Or without using the Geocoder API call, you could use this [list of countries](https://github.com/mihai-craita/countries_center_box "list") with their corresponding coordinates

Answer (score 5):

Turning a location name or address into a latitude/longitude like this is called geocoding.  Google Maps API now includes this capability: see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding

They include a sample application where you can type in an address, and it does work to simply type a country name.  I don't know if they are going to the exact center of the country.